# Dealing with the error: A different document with value xxxx already exists in the index

Tags: plone

What would cause multiple documents on my catalog to have the same "unique id"? Effectively an error like this:

> ERROR Products.ZCatalog A different document with value
>   'xxxx341a9f967070ff2b57922xxxx' already exists in the index.'

And how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Does running all upgrade-steps of p.a.discussions, help?

Comment: @downvoters: plone.org directs people to SO, to ask anything Plone-related. Please consider that, before acting on plone-tagged-quests, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ida. I'm on another Plone project for the next 2 days, but as soon as I can I'll look into that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error today.

In short: the UID index in portal_catalog (ZCatalog UUIDIndex) complains that you are trying to index multiple objects with the same UID

In my case it was caused by a zexp import of a folder that contained images that where already available in another folder.

**To reproduce:**

1. copy production buildout, database and blobstorage to staging server
2. do some changes to staging.com/folder1
3. move staging.com/galleries/gallery1 to staging.com/folder1
4. export staging.com/folder1 to folder1.zexp
5. remove production.com/folder1
6. use ZMI import/export on production.com/manage to import folder1.zexp

you'll get these errors for the gallery1 folder and all of its content items:

```
2015-06-15T17:58:22 ERROR Products.ZCatalog A different document with value '618a9ee3544a4418a1176ac0434cc63b' already exists in the index.'
```

**diagnosis**

production.com/resolveuid/618a9ee3544a4418a1176ac0434cc63b
will take you to production.com/galleries/gallery1/image1

whereas staging/resolveuid/618a9ee3544a4418a1176ac0434cc63b
will take you to staging.com/folder1/gallery1/image1

production.com/folder1/gallery1/image1 did get cataloged too, but because it has the same uid as production.com/galleries/gallery/image1 results of resolveuid, catalog queries, internal links and such stuff might be random

**how to repair**

In my case I think it's probably the best to either

- delete `production.com/galleries/gallery1` and run a clear and rebuild on the portal catalog.
- or replace production.com/folder1/gallery by production.com/galleries/gallery1 (delete, cut, paste)

If the objects with the same UID are not actually the same (as in my case) you might be able to give them new and uniques UIDS using `object._setUID('new-uid')` and rebuild the catalog afterwards.